# Access Google Drive API without creating WebApp?

Tags: google-drive-api

First I apologize if I'm a dolt and am missing something obvious, but I've spent a few hours scouring documentation and am lost.

I'm trying to write a python script that will upload a bunch of images to a single user's Google Drive.  The user already exists and will never change.  I am not writing a web app and don't plan to use any user interface whatsoever.  Everything will be done through code.

As best I can understand from the Google documentation, I have two choices:

1) Write a web app and register it to use the Drive DSK.  This of course requires having urls and such for the web app.

2) Create a service account, which ties my "app" to a new service account email.

Neither of these options works for me.  Is there any way to simply log in to a single user account and access their drive through python scripting?

Comment: why do the options you present not "work for you?"

Comment: Because I'm not writing a web app, it's just a script.  And I need to access a user account that already exists, not be tied to a new account as you get with a service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a deprecated API called [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps?csw=1) that would enable you to use the username and password for a login to access that Drive data.

But the basic idea is that you should be using something more secure -- from your users' point of view -- that allows them to authorize you without giving *you* their password.

For your use case it is possible that the user is you or someone you know and that you are accessing their account through a more personal kind of authorization. In that case, ClientLogin may be your best choice. If this is an application designed to be used by arbitrary users, the deprecation of ClientLogin is for a good reason and I would urge you to bite the bullet and choose one of the supported options.

Comment: The user has given me explicit authorization to access their drive. The script will never have any 'users' per se.  It will run once a month to programatically generate some files, and then upload them to this user's account so they can review them.

Comment: Is my use case very odd? It seems strange to me that api access through programatic login is a totally unsupported use case.

Comment: For this use case, you are still intended to have the user authorize your script through a web browser. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices

Comment: After reading about ClientLogin, it looks like even that requires the creation of a UI element to capture login information from the user, including a CAPTCHA.

Comment: The CAPTCHA requirement is never used, in my experience.

Comment: Well, I guess that answers that.  There is no way to do it.  User interaction is required.

Comment: You can do it with ClientLogin; if you know the user ID and password you want you can send them over the wire to get a session.

Comment: Got a login working with ClientLogin, sans CAPTCHA.  It's too bad I have to use libraries that have been deprecated over two years to do it though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to separate the authorization phase from the access phase. The authorization process needs to be run one time only, and can be done from a simple web site. The result of this is a refresh token which is analogous to a username/password. You will need to be aware of the security implications. Make sure you only grant drive.file scope to minimise the impact of a security breach.

Since you are uploading images, you might also want to look at the picassa api.