# Accessing one's personal Google Drive without registering an app?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'd like to access my personal Google Drive programmatically from Python, but I'm confused by [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). The Python aspects are trivial, but what I don't understand at all is the general authentication setup. The documentation links to other topics related to creating Google Cloud Projects, managing the apps, managing users, client IDs, creating credentials etc. All that seems overkill if I only want to access my personal Google Drive with just my personal user. Currently I'm stuck at the point that my app hasn't been verified by Google.

Is there a simpler way to authenticate with Google Drive without having to create an entire app?

Comment: I think you only need the app in `OAuth consent screen` - it does not need to be verified.

Comment: Apparently I can ignore that my app hasn't been verified, and I seem to have access now. Nonetheless, it feels strange having to register an official app for a personal use case.

Comment: You may want to review the answer from this similar post [Setting up Google Drive API in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273670/setting-up-google-drive-api-in-python)

Comment: @IrvinJayG. _You should be using a service account. Service accounts are like dummy users._ Isn't that even more involved considering that another account is involved? I just want to use my user / my account.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see this question when I wrote mine, but it may be a duplicate after all: [Access Google Drive API without creating WebApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613717/access-google-drive-api-without-creating-webapp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are serval ways to access data on Google apis.  There are three main things to consider.

1. Is this private user data, data that is owned by a user. Public videos posted to YouTube are public you dont need permission to view them.
2. Is this private user data data that is owned by a user. Your files on google drive are private no one can view them without your permission.
3. Is this private user data that is owned and controlled by the developer.  In other words you are not accessing data owned by users of your application.

For the first one you can use something called a public api key which just denotes to google whos application is accessing their api.

For the second option we use [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2), which will pop up a consent screen to request that the user consent to access of their data.  The issue with Oauth2 is that your app will need to be verified and while it is in the testing phase your refresh token will only be good for seven days, and then you will need to approve consent again.

For the third option you can use something called a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python).  Service accounts are like dummy users they can be pre authorized to access private data.  You do this by simply sharing for example your file on google drive with the service account.  It can then access that file without needing user interaction to click on the consent screen.

The nice thing about service accounts is that your app does not need to be verified.  By the sounds of it this is something you should consider.

When you create your [service account credentials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A&t=11s). Take the service account client looks like an email address and share the file with it just like you would any other user from the google drive web app

Here are a few tutorials on how to authorize with a service account. Neither are for Drive but you should be able to just grab the authorization section and apply it to your current drive service object.

- [Service-account python](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python)
- [Service-account python Google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py)
- [Should you be using a service account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTTTtwb7x7g&t=6s) - YouTube video explaining service accounts.
- [Setting up Google Drive API in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51278513/1841839) - answer from past me.

Comment: Looks like the short answer is: There is no simpler way. To be honest, a service account makes it even more complicated. I want to use **my** account to access **my** data. Use case: I use a Google Colab, and I want to have small Python script that syncs some training data to/from my local PC. There just is no app, the only user is me, the only developer is me, and my "app" certainly doesn't have users. Looks like Oath2 it is then. Basically I was just curious if the schizophrenic "self-consenting myself" can be avoided.

Comment: This is the away authorization works. There is no direct link between the project on Google cloud console and what you say is **my** account.  Its just a project that lets you develop applications that will access Google apis.   To get access to **my** account your application needs permission of the owner of **my** account, thats what Oauth is, its a way to grant consent to an application accessing user data.

Comment: If the only user is you then you should be using a service account.  You can set it up so that it has access to only your account by sharing a folder on your drive account any files in that folder the service account will have access to.

Comment: I can understand the frustration on OP's part. To the best of my understanding: NO, Google does not simply allow individual users to set up programmatic access to their own Google Drive data without having to pretend to be creating an "app". There is no way to get a simple "API key" to use the Drive API with your data, the only usecase they considered when designing this is one that appears to be designed with multiple users in mind. Perhaps they don't want to encourage use of Drive as an S3 replacement?

Comment: API keys are for public data.   Service accounts will let you access your own data without user intervention

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use files from our drive if we share it with the email of the service account, something like: 'name_sa@name_gcp_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.

Then you can use Google Drive API on files that you share before to the service account.

See the next ideas from the answer provided by [Linda Lawton - DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/linda-lawton-daimto):

> 3. Is this private user data that is owned and controlled by the developer. In other words you are not accessing data owned by users of
>    your application...
>
> For the third option you can use something called a service account.
> Service accounts are like dummy users they can be pre authorized to
> access private data. You do this by simply sharing for example your
> file on google drive with the service account. It can then access that
> file without needing user interaction to click on the consent screen...
>
> When you create your service account credentials. Take the service
> account client looks like an email address and share the file with it
> just like you would any other user from the Google Drive web app.

And by this method, we don't need to create the app.